# In which function should I pass the WaitGroup?

Tags: go

I have made a simple code example to understand the usage of pipeline, here it is.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 10) // Use buffered channel so as to avoid clogging
    ch2 := make(chan string, 10)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func1(i, ch1, &wg)
        go func2(ch1, ch2)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch1)
    for val := range ch2 {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}

func func1(seconds int, ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(seconds)
    ch <- seconds
}

func func2(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan string) {
    for range ch1 {
        ch2 <- "hello"
    }
    close(ch2)
}
```

Now, the problem is **I don't get consistent output** ( I understand it's some concurrency issue, which I haven't fully understood ).

#### Output

```
> go run pipeline-loop.go 
0
1
2
hello
hello

> go run pipeline-loop.go 
0
1
2
hello
hello
hello

> go run pipeline-loop.go 
0
1
2
hello
hello

> go run pipeline-loop.go 
0
1
2
hello
hello

> go run pipeline-loop.go 
0
1
2
hello
hello
panic: close of closed channel

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.func2(0xc00006c000, 0xc000056180)
    /home/projects/go-tuts/pipeline-loop.go:36 +0x72
created by main.main
    /home/projects/go-tuts/pipeline-loop.go:16 +0x10f
exit status 2
```

Another guy changed the code ( and it was working ) and put `func2` outside the loop but I want `func2` for each iteration of the `func1`.

#### Problem

So, I want to understand as to where should the `WaitGroup` and `close(ch)` be used ?

Thanks.
Temporarya
( A golang noobie )

### Update

Based on a user's answer, I changed the code, now I get output as expected ( but not the solution to this question ) but still there's a deadlock.
https://play.golang.org/p/O_rp_FLvNh8

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 10) // Use buffered channel so as to avoid clogging
    ch2 := make(chan string, 10)
    var wg1 sync.WaitGroup
    // var wg2 sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg1.Add(1)
        go func1(i, ch1)
        go func2(ch1, ch2, &wg1)
    }
    for val := range ch2 {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
    wg1.Wait()
    close(ch1)
    close(ch2)
}

// func func1(seconds int, ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
func func1(seconds int, ch chan<- int) {
    // defer wg.Done()
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(seconds) * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(seconds)
    ch <- seconds
}

func func2(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for range ch1 {
        ch2 <- "hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

In the loop, you are spawning multiple (3) goroutines that runs `func2`, and in `func2`, you send data to `ch2` and call `close(ch2)`. This is a problem. It can happen that when one goroutine is seding data to `ch2`, the other has closed that channel, which causes:

```
panic: close of closed channel

goroutine 6 [running]:
main.func2(0xc00006c000, 0xc000056180)
    /home/projects/go-tuts/pipeline-loop.go:36 +0x72
created by main.main
    /home/projects/go-tuts/pipeline-loop.go:16 +0x10f
exit status 2
```

In general, you don't need close a chanel multiple times - you only need to shut them once they are all finished. You need another `WaitGroup` for this; you need to pass both functions a `WaitGroup`.

Further reading: https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

UPDATE:

Personally I use a pattern for "works" that produce data into a same channel and the channel needs to be closed after all works are done:

```
for something {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
        work(ch)
        wg.Done()
    }
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close()
}()
```

I think it is a good idea that keeps the API clean from `WorkGroup` as `WorkGroup` is about how you sync the work instead of how the work is done.

I have changed your code into this pattern: https://play.golang.org/p/vdCNsxWhgyQ

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt reply, wouldn't it be fine if instead of passing waitgroup to `func1` I just passed it to `func2`, also, where do I put a `wait` for `func2` waitgroup, cause I'm using it in `main`, can you please add the code you think should be for `main`, that would help greatly

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.
So, the playground code, isn't good enough ?

Comment: @temporarya given the context, I would say the code is good enough. If you want to improve it, you'll need to get into details

Comment: This is what I was trying to make  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628157/what-improvements-can-be-done-to-this-go-watcher

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you only want one channel to read from ch1 and write to ch2.  There is not much point in creating 3 go-routines to do the same thing (and you also end up closing the same channel mutliple time which causes a panic as leaf bebop pointed out)

```
func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 10) // Use buffered channel so as to avoid clogging
    ch2 := make(chan string, 10)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func1(i, ch1, &wg)
    }
    go func2(ch1, ch2)
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch1)
    for val := range ch2 {
        fmt.Println(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the prompt reply Andrew, I suppose you're the same person from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/aou7f7/how_to_implement_pipeline_for_goroutines/eg42qm2), anyway that's out of question.
But the thing is I want each `func1`'s output to be handled by a new `func2` because in this sample code it might look small but in actual it's a webcrawler, `func1` fetches data and `func2` processes it to store it in DB.
That's why it's needed.

Comment: With your current soln all the func1 outputs go to the same channel so you have not control over which func2 handles them - they might all end up going through the same one anyway. Maybe you need multiple channels instead of just ch1 - one for each func1, then you need no WaitGroups - each func1 just closes its chan when finished. Just a thought.

(BTW Not me in reddit)

Comment: @andrew-w-phillips If I create multiple channels, how would I be able to handle it's output then ?